Как выполнить декремент байта равным 0 в Python?
Имеется кусок кода на Python:
>>> bt2 = bytearray(2)
>>> bt2[0] -= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
>>> bt2[1] -= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)

Для меня это неожиданное поведение. В виду того, что у меня есть опыт разработки на языке ассемблера архитектуры x86-64 я ожидаю, что при уменьшении байта равным 0x0 на 1 получу значение 0xFF. А если увеличу байт равным 0xFF на 1, то получу 0x0. Но вместо этого вижу брошенное ValueError.
У меня два вопроса:

Есть ли в Python возможность эмулировать "байты", то есть при декременте 0x0 получить 0xFF ?
Почему в Python подобное поведение?



Такое поведение нормально для большинства пользователей. Вы работали с ассемблером, где из-за ограничений железа, для простоты, сделана арифметика по модулю. То что привычно вам, не является нормой (программисты на ассемблере в меньшинстве). Всё-таки до нуля идёт минус единица. 1. Используйте % : bt2[0] = (bt2[0] - 1) % 256.


Да, но в JavaScript существует Uint8 и там как раз операция декремента 0 приводит к 0xFF. Значит арифметика по модулю вполне очевидна и для программистов работающих с высокоуровневым ЯП

Пример самописного класса: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2980422/8324991

@sys_dev привычное не значит единственно возможное. Например, Rust - хоть и высокоуровневый язык, но ориентированный на железо. Тем не менее, в отладочном режиме, переполнение при вычитании приведет к панике. Это сознательный выбор, потому, что в первую очередь язык ориентируется на безопасность и недвусмысленность. Python конечно не такой безопасный, но один из его главных принципов "Explicit is better than implicit". JS обычно предпочитает implicit

Можно воспользоваться numpy
import numpy as np

bt2 = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.uint8)
print(bt2)  # [0 0]

bt2[0] -= 1
print(bt2)  # [255   0]

bt2[1] -= 1
print(bt2)  # [255 255]

bt2[0] += 1
print(bt2)  # [  0 255]

bt2[1] += 1
print(bt2)  # [0 0]

bt2 = bytearray(bt2) 
print(bt2) # bytearray(b'\x00\x00')


Спасибо! Очень интересный способ и приводит к достаточно понятному коду!

Не просто Numpy, а конкретным его типом uint8 )

Как вариант:
def decrement_byte(b: int, flag: str) -> int:
    
    if flag == "+":
        return (b + 1) % 256
    elif flag == "-":
        return (b - 1) % 256
    else:
        raise ValueError("flag must be either '+' or '-'")


bt2 = bytearray(2)
print(bt2[0])  # Вывод: 0

bt2[0] = decrement_byte(bt2[0], "-")
print(bt2[0])  # Вывод: 255

bt2[0] = decrement_byte(bt2[0], "+")
print(bt2[0])  # Вывод: 0

Четкое ограничение значений байтов помогает избежать ошибок, связанных с переполнением и неожиданным поведением, которое может возникнуть в языках низкого уровня.

Да, один из вариантов написать самому тип "Байт" с поддержкой операций декремента/инкремента. Но мне кажется, что подобное все-таки должно быть в Python.
